# Is there an intent filter to catch the start of a download from the browser?

Tags: android, intentfilter

In several browser apps including the default Browser and Chrome, if you long press a link there is an option called "Save link". Tapping this option will start a download using a DownloadManager.

I am trying to find an Intent Filter that will give the user an option to use my app to handle the download instead. I'm not having any luck finding one.

I know from looking into the DownloadManager that you can get broadcasts when a download finishes, but I would like to be able to know about it before it starts.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not interact with [`DownloadManger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) though `Intent`s.  Instead, you use [`getSystemService(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) to get a handle to it.  Thus, alternative download managers are not really supported.